# How to play items from a listbox with continuous play?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I need some help with how I can take my listbox and read the selected song and play that song, and then allow for the next song to be played after that song. My issue is that I have a MediaEnded for my MediaElement, but I'm not sure how to make it play when you click on the item or to continue playing after you have finished a song. Here is my code:

Xaml.cs:

```
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace MusicalCloud
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private int currentSongIndex = -1;
        private bool mediaPlayerIsPlaying = false;
        private bool userIsDraggingSlider = false;
        ObservableCollection<string> mFileList;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            GetFiles(@"E:\Dropbox\Music");
            this.DataContext = mFileList;
        }

        private void GetFiles(string folderPath)
        {
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath);
             mFileList = new ObservableCollection<string>(files);
        }

        private void PlayPause(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (playPauseButton.Content == FindResource("Play"))
            {
                musicDisplay.Play();
                mediaPlayerIsPlaying = true;
                playPauseButton.Content = FindResource("Pause");
            }
            else
            {
                musicDisplay.Pause();
                mediaPlayerIsPlaying = false;
                playPauseButton.Content = FindResource("Play");
            }
        }

        private void Player_MediaEnded(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(currentSongIndex == -1)
            {
                currentSongIndex = lstSongs.SelectedIndex;
            }
            currentSongIndex++;
            if(currentSongIndex < lstSongs.Items.Count)
            {
                musicDisplay.Play(lstSongs.Items[currentSongIndex]);
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }

        private void openMenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
            open.Multiselect = true;
            open.Filter = "All files (*.*) | *.*";
            if (open.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                musicDisplay.Source = new Uri(open.FileName);
            }

        }

        private void exitMenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="MusicalCloud.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Musical Cloud" Height="400" Width="600">
<Window.Resources>
    <Image x:Key="Play" Source="Images/play.png" Height="30" Width="30" />
    <Image x:Key="Pause" Source="Images/pause.png" Height="30" Width="30" />
</Window.Resources>
<DockPanel>
    <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <MenuItem Header="_Open"
                  Click="openMenuItem_Click"/>
        <MenuItem Header="_Close"
                  Click="exitMenuItem_Click"/>
    </Menu>
    <Grid Background="DarkGray">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="35*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="65*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="85*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="15*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <StackPanel x:Name="musicFinder"
                    Grid.Row="0"
                    Grid.Column="0">
            <ListBox x:Name="lstSongs"
                     ItemsSource="{Binding}">

            </ListBox>
        </StackPanel>

        <MediaElement x:Name="musicDisplay"
                    Grid.Row="0"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    LoadedBehavior="Manual"
                    MediaEnded="Player_MediaEnded"
                    Source="{Binding ElementName=musicFinder, Path=SelectedItem}">

        </MediaElement>

        <Grid x:Name="mediaControls"
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    Grid.Column="0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="20*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="20*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="20*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="20*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="20*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="20*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Button x:Name="backButton"
                Height="30"
                Width="30"
                Grid.Row="0"
                Grid.Column="0">
                <Image Source="Images/previous.png" />
            </Button>

            <Button x:Name="rewindButton"
                    Height="30"
                    Width="30"
                    Grid.Column="1">
                <Image Source="Images/fast_backward.png" />
            </Button>

            <Button x:Name="playPauseButton"
                    Height="40"
                    Width="40"
                    Grid.Column="2"
                    Click="PlayPause">
                <DynamicResource ResourceKey="Play" />
            </Button>

            <Button x:Name="ffButton"
                    Height="30"
                    Width="30"
                    Grid.Column="3">
                <Image Source="Images/fast_forward.png" />
            </Button>

            <Button x:Name="skipButton"
                    Height="30"
                    Width="30"
                    Grid.Column="4">
                <Image Source="Images/next.png" />
            </Button>
        </Grid>

        <StackPanel x:Name="timeLine"
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    Grid.Column="1">
        </StackPanel>

        </Grid>
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: maintain a playlist.

Comment: @pushpraj How would I go about doing that? Since this is the first time I've dabbled in MediaElements.

Comment: as a suggestion create a collection field for playlist, create a property for current song and another for selected song. then bind the current song to media element and selected song to selected item of listbox. when the selected song change, add it to playlist, and when the current song is finished pick the next song from playlist and set it to current song property.

Comment: any success? anything blocking?

Comment: I'm pretty much at a road block right now. I've just been searching and trying to figure out what to do with what you have said, but I'm still confused as ever.

Comment: never mind, I'll prepare an example for you to get started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is sample for what I mentioned in the comments

```
<DockPanel>
    <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <MenuItem Header="_Open"
                  Click="openMenuItem_Click" />
        <MenuItem Header="_Close"
                  Click="exitMenuItem_Click" />
    </Menu>
    <Grid Background="DarkGray">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="35*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="65*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="85*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="15*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <StackPanel x:Name="musicFinder"
                    Grid.Row="0"
                    Grid.Column="0">
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding FileList}"
                     SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMedia}">

            </ListBox>
        </StackPanel>

        <MediaElement x:Name="musicDisplay"
                      Grid.Row="0"
                      Grid.Column="1"
                      LoadedBehavior="Manual"
                      MediaEnded="Player_MediaEnded"
                      MediaOpened="Player_MediaOpened"
                      MediaFailed="Player_MediaEnded"
                      Source="{Binding CurrentMedia}">
        </MediaElement>

        <Grid x:Name="mediaControls"
              Grid.Row="1"
              Grid.Column="0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="20*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="20*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="20*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="20*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="20*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="20*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Button x:Name="backButton"
                    Height="30"
                    Width="30"
                    Grid.Row="0"
                    Grid.Column="0">
                |&lt;
            </Button>

            <Button x:Name="rewindButton"
                    Height="30"
                    Width="30"
                    Grid.Column="1">
                &lt; &lt;
            </Button>

            <Button x:Name="playPauseButton"
                    Height="40"
                    Width="40"
                    Grid.Column="2"
                    Click="PlayPause">
                &gt;
            </Button>

            <Button x:Name="ffButton"
                    Height="30"
                    Width="30"
                    Grid.Column="3">
                &gt; &gt;
            </Button>

            <Button x:Name="skipButton"
                    Height="30"
                    Width="30"
                    Grid.Column="4">
                &gt;|
            </Button>
        </Grid>

        <StackPanel x:Name="timeLine"
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    Grid.Column="1">
        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
</DockPanel>
```

I have replaced few of the images from the xaml  you may replace them back

code behind

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private bool mediaPlayerIsPlaying = false;

    public ObservableCollection<string> FileList { get; set; }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        GetFiles(@"E:\vids");
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    private void GetFiles(string folderPath)
    {
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath);
        FileList = new ObservableCollection<string>(files);
    }

    private void PlayPause(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (mediaPlayerIsPlaying)
        {
            musicDisplay.Pause();
            mediaPlayerIsPlaying = false;
        }
        else
        {
            musicDisplay.Play();
            mediaPlayerIsPlaying = true;
        }
    }

    private void Player_MediaEnded(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int currentSongIndex = FileList.IndexOf(SelectedMedia);
        currentSongIndex++;
        if (currentSongIndex < FileList.Count)
        {
            SelectedMedia = FileList[currentSongIndex] as string;
            Play();
        }
        else
        {
            CurrentMedia = null;
        }
    }

    private void Player_MediaOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        mediaPlayerIsPlaying = true;
    }

    void Play(string media = null)
    {
        musicDisplay.Stop();
        mediaPlayerIsPlaying = false;
        CurrentMedia = media ?? SelectedMedia;
        PlayPause(null, null);
    }

    private void openMenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
        open.Multiselect = true;
        open.Filter = "All files (*.*) | *.*";
        if (open.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Play(open.FileName);
        }

    }

    private void exitMenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }

    public string CurrentMedia
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(CurrentMediaProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CurrentMediaProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for CurrentMedia.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CurrentMediaProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("CurrentMedia", typeof(string), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public string SelectedMedia
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(SelectedMediaProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedMediaProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for SelectedMedia.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedMediaProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedMedia", typeof(string), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(null, (s, e) => (s as MainWindow).Play()));
}
```

I have created two properties SelectedMedia and CurrentMedia and used them to control the listbox and media element.

I have also changed some of the existing code, you may please adjust as necessary.

above sample will play all the items from the list in sequence, also it will play anything which is opened by the menu and will resume back to the list once finished.

give it a try and see if it is close enough

Comment: This is very close, but my listbox doesn't show the music that should be there.

Comment: @Donald check if it is because of `GetFiles(@"E:\vids");` your original code line was `GetFiles(@"E:\Dropbox\Music");`

Comment: Even with it being GetFiles(@"E\Dropbox\Music"); it still doesn't show.

Comment: @Donald could you try debug and see why it is not there? I do not see any such issue. perhaps you can try to create a new project first with this code, instead of merging with your current code and understand how it works. then it would be much easier to make changes in your existing code.

Comment: I figured out the problem, now everything works as planned! I just forgot the public in front of the ObservableCollection. Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use such a method. It is not the best way but enough ;

```
private void Media_Ended(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    media.Position = TimeSpan.Zero;
    media.Play();
}
```